# Repopulating user inputs after successful validation

Tags: validation, laravel, redirect, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I am trying to create a search form where the user has to select from some dropdown menus and enter text in one of a few fields. The problem is I am redisplaying the search page with results below it. To do this I am not redirecting, I am just returning a view with the datasets I need compacted along with it.

Is there any way to get to retrieve input similar to how you would do this Input::old('x') when you were redirecting after failed validation?

The routes are:

```
Route::get('search', ['as' => 'main.search.get', 'uses' => 'MainController@showSearchPage']);

Route::post('search', ['as' => 'main.search.post', 'uses' => 'MainController@showSearchResults']);
```

Example of code I have in the view:

```
 {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'main.search.post', 'class' => 'form-inline align-form-center', 'role' => 'form')) !!}

 <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('product_code', 'Product Code: ',['class' => 'control-label  label-top']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('product_code', Input::old('product_code'), ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
</div>
```

So when you submit a search, it calls showSearchResults which then returns a view if it succeeds, if it fails validation via my SearchRequest class it gets redirected to the main.search.get route, errors are printed and input is returned to the fields.

I have done a lot of searching and have come up more or less empty handed, it would be nice if there was a way to say ->withInput() when returning a view (not redirecting) or something.

Currently my only solution is to Input::flash() but since I am not redirecting that data persists for an extra refresh. That isn't a terribly big deal at this point, but I was wondering if anyone else had a better solution.

**Edit - Code below from controller where view is returned:**

```
...

   Input::flash();
   return view('main.search', compact('results', 'platformList', 'versionList', 'customerList', 'currencyList', 'customer', 'currency'));
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the controller's methods code? Looks like you are forgetting one step before redirecting, because laravel can do that actually.

Comment: I am not redirecting, I am returning a view, that's the whole reason I am having issues, I am not redirecting, just returning views.

Comment: are you using javascript? I do not see the code when you are returning the view

Comment: I added a snippet above from the controller where it's being returned.  Currently it shows my workaround (using Input::flash())

Comment: One question, are you submitting the search data via form element?

Comment: Correct, I added the form open element code in the view sample as well if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution that worked for me was to add the following line into the controller.

```
session(['_old_input' => $request->input()]);
```

---

Now I'll explain how it works.

In the view, the global function *old()* is called:

```
<input type="username" id="username" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
```

This function is in *vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php*

```
function old($key = null, $default = null)
{
    return app('request')->old($key, $default);
}
```

This calls *Illuminate\Http\Request->old()*:

```
public function old($key = null, $default = null)
{
    return $this->session()->getOldInput($key, $default);
}
```

Which calls *Illuminate\Session\Store->getOldInput()*:

```
public function getOldInput($key = null, $default = null)
{
    $input = $this->get('_old_input', []);
    return Arr::get($input, $key, $default);
}
```

This call is looking for **_old_input** in the session. So the solution is to add the input to the session using this value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually this solution caused the input to be permanently stored in the users session until they entered something new. I only wanted the input to be preserved in the fields for one submission, the use of Input::flash() I mentioned above kept it for two reloads, which was annoying but workable, your solution keeps it permanently because you are putting it into the session permanently, not as a flash.
Your answer format was great though, I learned something about Laravels internals. :-)

Comment: I agree. I think your solution is better. I actually replaced my snippet with your answer in my code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request` instead of `old` since its the post request

```
change {{old('product_code')}} to {{request('product_code')}}
```